# Reading Web Part custom properties using JavaScript client object model in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

Is it possible to read visual web part custom properties using Java script client object model in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read directly from the webpart. But you can however write the values out in the control.

```
Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<script type='javascript'>var customWebPartProperty1 = '{0}';</script>", myWebPart.CustomProperty1)));
```

You can also write them to hidden fields in the webpart instead if that makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. currently i am writing the value in hidden field. it seems it is possible in sp2013 [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247072%28v=office.15%29.aspx. as get_properties() is available which is not there in sp 2010.       [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee552783%28v=office.14%29.aspx. Is it possible to read properties value using SPServices or any other clientside js?

Comment: It seems like get_properties() only gets the built-in-properties of the Webpart in SP2013. Did you get further information about custom properties?

Answer (score 0):

i use this JS code to get the values of the custom properties i created.

```
 var propVal = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("MyPropName"));
```

//when getquerystringparameter is undefined you can also copy paste this

```
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params =
            document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
```

no idea if this works in 2010 , hope it helps